# WinSCP Keep up to date command stuck on checking for changes

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, winscp

I'm currently testing `keepuptodate` command in my local environment in order to deploy correct full command on a server and I got a problem with `keepuptodate`.

I'm on Windows 10 with "Xlight FTP Server" as test server, and I saved access as "test_local" on WinSCP (I know it's not a good practice but it's just a test)

The command I wrote in the shell is

```
WinSCP.exe test_local /Console /Script=script.txt
```

and the `script.txt` contains

```
option batch on
option confirm off
option transfer automatic
keepuptodate -delete F:\mirror_test /
close
exit
```

I also tried by logging the script with logging enabled

```
/log="F:\WinSCP.log"
```

option and here's the log

```
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.590 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.590 Using FTP protocol.
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.590 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2020-03-08 15:07:06.591 PWD
< 2020-03-08 15:07:06.690 257 "/"
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.691 Getting current directory name.
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.691 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2020-03-08 15:07:06.691 Script: Active session: [1] anonymous@192.168.1.81
> 2020-03-08 15:07:06.692 Script: option transfer binary
< 2020-03-08 15:07:06.692 Script: transfer        binary    
> 2020-03-08 15:07:06.693 Script: keepuptodate F:\mirror_test /
< 2020-03-08 15:07:06.693 Script: Checking for changes started, press 'Ctrl-C' to stop...
< 2020-03-08 15:07:06.694 Script: Looking for subfolders in 'F:\mirror_test'...
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.694 Keep up to date: Looking for subfolders in 'F:\mirror_test'...
< 2020-03-08 15:07:06.705 Script: Checking for changes in folder 1...
. 2020-03-08 15:07:06.707 Keep up to date: Checking for changes in folder 1...
. 2020-03-08 15:07:36.532 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2020-03-08 15:07:36.532 TYPE A
< 2020-03-08 15:07:37.032 200 Type set to A.
```

And then everything just stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keepuptodate` command does something, when something changes only. It does not synchronize the directories, if they are not synchronized, when the command starts.

For synchronizing directories use [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize).

And you can follow that by `keepuptodate`, if you still want to keep synchronizing changes continuously.